# php script response to ajax does not work

Tags: php, ajax

For a hobby, I am building a simple chat script and would like to implement a "/kick" feature in it. For that, I have a form for chat input and send.php file that processes input. I would like to be able to /kick all users and redirect them to login.php with ajax. But the problem I have is that echo from send.php seems not to get to ajax and it does not fire redirect. So far I have:

send.php

```
...

elseif($_POST['text'] == "/kick")
    {

        unset($_SESSION['username']);
        unset($_SESSION['enterTime']);
        session_destroy();
        $sql = "DELETE FROM sjednice";

        mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

        echo "1";


    }

...
```

ajax

```
var intervalTimer = window.setInterval(function kick(){
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $.ajax({
                  method: 'post',
                  url: 'send.php',
                  dataType: 'text',
                  success: function(data) {


                    if(data == "1")
                    {


                        //this is not getting executed
                        window.location.href = "login.php";


                    }


                  }
  });
  });
  },100);
```

**Edit**:
I have this jquery form library that handles form submit without refreshing the whole page, so chat would not refresh all the time. The form action is to send.php separate file and send.php caontains header redirect in this elseif in the above code.

Could this be the reason why php header location is not redirecting? Because I have tried php header to redirect but only in this case it does not work.

[image]

Comment: Is the AJAX request made to the server?  What is the server's response?  In your browser's debugging tools, what specifically happens?

Comment: Looks like an expensive hobby :) you need to write more and correct codes to check users status and log them out.

Comment: I tried to console.log to see the output, as I would expect 1 to show, but nothing, and no errors in console show

Comment: Also, why are you adding a `document.ready` handler *10 times every second*?  How many AJAX requests are you actually making?

Comment: @ZoranKoprek: The console is only one of many tools available.  Use the network tab and the script debugger within the debugging tools for more information.

Comment: yeah I dont understand ajax so I got here, sorry for that

Comment: You're also looking for a specific value in the server-side code: `elseif($_POST['text'] == "/kick")`  But your client-side code doesn't send any data to the server.  Honestly, there's *a lot* wrong here.  You'd probably do well to scrap this and start over with something simpler, adding one feature at a time.

Comment: A "simple chat script" sounds like an oxymoron to me. To redirect someone you don't even need AJAX, though. Just do `location = 'your_location.php';` on the Client.

Comment: @StackSlave, good point I think, but php header redirect does not redirect at all, please take a look edit in my question

Comment: Get rid of that interval and just `$(()=> { /* all jquery in here */ yourFormElement.submit(e=>{ /*run your ajax here */ e.preventDefault(); }) };`. Yeah, that is wrapped in `.ready` like that.